# Manage displayed content on external data based on data available in SFMC or Pardot

Tags: marketing-cloud, pardot, dynamic-content

I'm looking for a solution that will allow to manage displayed content on external website, displayed content should be dependent on data from SFMC or Pardot and be easily configured preferably by drag-n-drop (something similar to content builder Dynamic Content Block - like for user with gender=male show content A).
Is there a possibility to achieve something like that with Predictive Content in SFMC? Or are there any external apps easily integrated with SFMC/Pardot that will allow for that?

Answer (score 0):

With Pardot you use Advanced Dynamic Content. [See explanation here in Pardot Help section](http://help.pardot.com/customer/portal/articles/2128451-advanced-dynamic-content-overview).

With Marketing Cloud there is no easy way to achieve this. Dynamic Content Blocks are used for email and Predictive Web (part of Personalization Builder) is used for content distribution based on past prospect behaviour.